# Magento 2.2.7: how to run composer update command under Ampps/Xampp php version instead to base php

Tags: magento2, composer

I am using LAMP on which I have PHP 7.2
I install Ampps on which I have PHP 7.1
How I have to run `composer update` command? If I run it gave me PHP version error (definitely it will give 2.2.7 don't require php7.2)
How I have to run composer using Ampps's PHP version instead of base PHP version.

Comment: Magento 2.2.X only supports PHP 7.0 and 7.1

Comment: yes it is. but need solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. You have to run update composer like the following.

```
/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

you have to give path of your required php (the version using on Ampps or Xampp) in first argument like `/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/bin/php` and in second argument gave composer path like `/usr/local/bin/composer` then add `update` at the end.

Comment: I do not recommend executing composer with sudo

Comment: I had updated now try and share your view for answer. I had updated my my packages successfully using above.
- Installing illuminate/encryption (v5.5.44): Downloading (100%)